# Writing to output stream in shell

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have a piece of code as below -

```
#!/bin/sh

keyA=`openssl rand -base64 32| tr -d "="`
keyB=`openssl rand -base64 32| tr -d "="`

#Encrypt KeyA with KeyB to make keyC
ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase /root/passkeyC.txt
```

It generates two keys A & B and I need to generate a third key C. When the command for key C is executed, an output screens asks for user input -

```
Passphrase to wrap:
Wrapping passphrase:
```

I need to output the keyA to Passphrase to wrap & keyB to Wrapping passphrase from the script the itself. Don't want it to be displayed on user screen and key A to be used as Passphrase to wrap & keyB as Wrapping passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [expect](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) to easily do the automatic input for you.

Using expect, it would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
keyA=`openssl rand -base64 32| tr -d "="` 
keyB=`openssl rand -base64 32| tr -d "="`

#Encrypt KeyA with KeyB to make keyC. Use expect to automatically fill in the interactive dialogue

expect -c "spawn ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase /root/passkeyC.txt;  expect wrap; send \"$keyA\r\"; expect passphrase;  send \"$keyB\r\"; interact"
```

However this **won't hide** the keys from the user. ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase doesn't seem to have any options for it either. 
Perhaps you can wrap your script in another script that isn't ran in interactive mode. How do you want to run your script? (when?)

Answer (score 1):

`ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase` reads from standard input if the second argument is `-`, so you can use a here document to feed the keys.

```
keyA=$(openssl rand -base64 32 | tr -d "=")
keyB=$(openssl rand -base64 32 | tr -d "=")

# Encrypt KeyA with KeyB to make keyC
ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase /root/passkeyC.txt - <<EOF
$keyA
$keyB
EOF
```

This is a slightly more efficient method than shown in the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man1/ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase.1.html), as it avoids an extra pipe.

```
printf  "%s\n%s" "$keyA" "$keyB" | ecryptfs-wrap-passphrase /root/passkeyC.txt -
```